# Target element by attr then append class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `li` tag that looks like :

```
<li class="item maybe" data-selected="1"></li>
<li class="item confused" data-selected="2"></li>
<li class="item why" data-selected="3"></li>
```

I then have three other elements that look like :

```
<li class="display"></li>
<li class="display"></li>
<li class="display"></li>
```

I'm trying to on select of one of the elements append the class to my 2nd list of elements.

So if I selected the `li` tag with `data-selector="1"` then my first `li` tag in my display list will have the class `maybe` added.

This is what i've tried so far, but i'm getting undefined when I console log my var out :

```
if ($('.item').attr('data-selected') == 1) {
  var itemClassAdd = $('.item').find("[data-selected='1']").attr('class');
  console.log(itemClassAdd);

  $(".display").addClass(itemClassAdd);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$.find`looks in the descendants of selected node, you need `$.filter`. Then `.class()` and `.data()` are your friends ^^

Answer (score 2):

I perform action in a click event for convenience:

```
$("li.item").click(function(){
    var index = $(this).data("selected");

    $("li.display").eq(index - 1).addClass($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

If you don't need class item:

```
$("li.item").click(function(){
    var index = $(this).data("selected");
    var c = $(this).attr("class").replace("item ", "");        

    $("li.display").eq(index - 1).addClass(c);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The class and the attribute are on the *same* element, so you use a compound selector, not `find`:

```
var itemClassAdd = $('.item[data-selected="1"]').attr('class');
```

But note that

```
if ($('.item').attr('data-selected') == 1) {
```

will only branch of the *first* element matching `.item` has `data-selected="1"`, which may or may not be what you want.

**Live Example:**

```js
if ($('.item').attr('data-selected') == 1) {
    var itemClassAdd = $('.item[data-selected="1"]').attr('class');
    $(".display").addClass(itemClassAdd);
}
```

```css
.maybe {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item maybe" data-selected="1">maybe</li>
  <li class="item confused" data-selected="2">confused</li>
  <li class="item why" data-selected="3">why</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="display">d1</li>
  <li class="display">d2</li>
  <li class="display">d3</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```